# How to Implement the Design for This Layout: Swift (UIButton)

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have this layout. 1,2,3, and 4 represent UIButtons. The red is a UIImageView. What is the best way to create these buttons using Swift.

I thought about using a png image that has transparent information. It would create the UIButton with a width and height. See image 2.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think maybe the best way is using mask

Comment: Or you can also use CGCoreGraphic for custom drawing

Comment: CAShapeLayer is also an option.

Comment: I don't want the hit box to be outside the design itself. So my solution wouldn't really work. Any help as to how I could go about creating this using any of the aforementioned suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured the best (non-time-consuming) option was to use the OBShapedButton library which takes care of my issue by creating an image mask.

Objective-C Version:
https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton/tree/master/OBShapedButton

Swift Version:
https://gist.github.com/clmntcrl/8e4cab3ed7d1e7da47e7